# How to create a directory and store its name in a value?

Tags: command-line, scripts, perl

I want to create a directory and I want to print the directory as a name.

My code is as follows:

```
#here $directory = www(subdirectory name)
#in @missingfiles I have 1 gif and 1 html file.
my @createDir = `mkdir -p ./RubbishBin/$directory`;
say ("Folder taking @createDir");
my $q = `cp -r @missingFiles @createingDir`;
```

In my output, I will get only "`Folder taking @createDir`" and not print the file name.

How can I get this type of output "`Folder taking RubbishBin/www`" in my output.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the `mkdir` command's *standard output* to `@createDir`. Normally, `mkdir` doesn't produce any output - however you can make it do so by adding the `-v` (`--verbose`) option.

Ex.

```
$ perl -e 'my $directory = "www"; my $createDir = `mkdir -vp "./RubbishBin/$directory"`; print $createDir'
mkdir: created directory './RubbishBin'
mkdir: created directory './RubbishBin/www'
```

Comment: After that, I will try to move the file in that folder. But I can not move that file in that folder.